# Why am i getting no error but the code isnt working?

Tags: python, list, random, definition

I am trying to write a code for class that identifies the probability that two or more people given can have the same birthday out of a group by running this experiment 10^6 times and then calculating the fraction of times during which two or more people had the same birthday. I attached the code below, but when I try and run it absolutely nothing happens. It gives no error message, it just stops working. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
    -
 import random

 def calc_birthday_probability (num_people):

     random.seed (2020) # Don't change this value
     num_trials = 1000000
     probability = 0
     list1 = []
     num_people = int(input())
     repeats = 0
     for i in range(0,num_trials+1):

         for i in range (0,num_people+1):
            list1.append(random.randint (1,3655))
            for i in list1:
                if list1.count(i)>1:
                    repeats +=1
                    i = i+1
                i = i+1

    prob = repeats//num_trials
    probability = probability + prob

    return probability

a = calc_birthday_probability(10)

print(a)
```

Comment: why don't you debug you code?

Comment: Your indentation is a complete mess. Can you please make sure that is correct in the first place. If I copy your code I get one error message after the other.

Comment: I think you meant 365 (number of days in a year), rather than 3655.

Answer (score 3):

**num_people = int(input())**
Classic, you are already given the parameter in the function but you are retaking input for it. Your program simply waits for you to enter something.

Usually, a good trick when a python program does nothing despite it being expected to perform some kind of action is to check whether or not it is waiting for some kind of input :)

Edit #1: as @rkatkam noted, you are using the same loop variable (specifically, **i**) for both of the for loops.

Answer (score 2):

In all the `for` loops in the function, you have used variable `i` and so its scope is improper to define too.

Something like following should work, it worked for me:

```
def calc_birthday_probability (num_people):

    random.seed (2020) # Don't change this value
    num_trials = 1000000
    probability = 0
    list1 = []
    repeats = 0
    for i in range(0,num_trials+1):

        for j in range (0,num_people+1):
            list1.append(random.randint (1,3655))
            for k in list1:
                if list1.count(j)>1:
                    repeats +=1
                    k = k+1

    prob = repeats//num_trials
    probability = probability + prob

    return probability
```

And some tips:

1. Try testing your code with smaller `num_trials` initially till you find the results are accurate.
2. You have argument that accepts the value of `num_people` and the function also has an `input()` for the same.
3. When you trying to print output, print some other string as well along, to identify if the function finished its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version of your code

```
import random

def calc_birthday_probability(number_of_people = 30, num_trials=1000):
    dups_found = 0
    for _ in range(num_trials):
        birthdays = [random.randint (1,365) for _ in range(number_of_people)]

        # set of birthdays which are duplicates
        duplicates = set(x for x in birthdays if birthdays.count(x) > 1)

        if len(duplicates) >= 1:
            dups_found += 1   # increment since at least one duplicate

    return number_of_people, dups_found/num_trials * 100


num_people = int(input("Number of people: "))
print(f'{calc_birthday_probability(num_people, 1000):.2f}%')
```

**Test**

Testing with only 1,000 trials since sufficient for results to compare with [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

```
for num_people in range(1, 52, 2):
  print(f'{num_people} --> {calc_birthday_probability(num_people, 1000):.2f}%')
```

**Output**

```
1 --> 0.00%
3 --> 0.40%
5 --> 3.10%
7 --> 6.10%
9 --> 9.90%
11 --> 13.70%
13 --> 19.00%
15 --> 25.30%
17 --> 34.60%
19 --> 37.70%
21 --> 46.50%
23 --> 53.30%
25 --> 57.30%
27 --> 59.60%
29 --> 70.40%
31 --> 72.40%
33 --> 77.90%
35 --> 81.60%
37 --> 84.30%
39 --> 87.90%
41 --> 89.30%
43 --> 93.40%
45 --> 93.70%
47 --> 95.00%
49 --> 96.10%
51 --> 96.60%
```